# Crossfire HD7950 with R9 380? Or other 300 series card?

Tags: amd-radeon, crossfire

I have a HD7950 (Sapphire Dual-X OC). I have read that it can be Crossfire'd with a R9 280X but *can I crossfire it with any R9 300 series cards?*

(I think the 380 is the equivalent to the 280X and the HD7950...)

Comment: not super familiar with AMD, but I seem to recall that AMD sometimes re-badges older cards - so they're the same internals, and can do crossfire. This is VERY specific to certain pairs of models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R9 280 and R9 380 are based on different chipsets (Tahiti vs Tonga, respectively).

To my knowledge, the 300 series does not have a Tahiti-based card. So, the answer to both questions is no.